# json object returns nothing in WCF data service WebInvoke VB Odata

Tags: asp.net, json, vb.net, odata, wcf-data-services

Hope someone can help.  Really pulling my hair out and starting to think i should have not used wcf data services.  Its been easy to get odata from the service so i thought i could send json object from my javascript code and read the contents as an object in my service But it returns nothing.

My javascript:

```
 var vname = [];
 var obj = { myobject: { frmid: "test", frmval: "1111" } }
 vname.push(obj)

 $.ajax({
      url: "MyWCFDataService.svc/SendItems",
      type: "POST",
      dataType: "json",
      contentType: "json",
      data: { myobject: JSON.stringify(vname) },
      success: function () {
          alert("success :-)");
      },
      error: function () {
          alert("fail :-(");
      }
  });
```

My class and function in my svc

```
<DataServiceKeyAttribute("id")> _
Public Class tobject
    Public Property id As Integer
    Public Property frmid As String
    Public Property frmval As String
End Class

<WebInvoke()> _
Public Function SendItems(myobject As String) As Boolean
           ' have to ask for string as errors when asking for tobject
    Return True ' nothing here yet as cannot get json object
End Function
```

My first venture into wcf data services and jquery.  Was hoping to return a list of textboxes names and values to a wcf data service to process.  Is it possible with the wcf data service?

Comment: There's no need to use JSON.stringify, you want to send json, not a string version of it.

Comment: Thanks, but if i dont, it sends the data as undefined=&undefined=&undefined= . json.stringify sends it correctly for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so i created a new wcf data service, removed the inherits dataservice reference and initializeservice sub.

javascript:

```
vname.push( { frmid: "test", frmval: "1111" })

$.ajax({
  url: "MyWCFDataService.svc/SendItems",
  type: "POST",
  dataType: "json",
  contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
  data: { JSON.stringify(vname) },
  success: function () {
      alert("success :-)");
  },
  error: function () {
      alert("fail :-(");
  }
```

});

service:

```
Public Class tobject
    Public Property frmid As String
    Public Property frmval As String
End Class


<OperationContract>
<WebInvoke(ResponseFormat:=WebMessageFormat.Json, RequestFormat:=WebMessageFormat.Json)> _
Public Function SendItems(anyobjectname As List(Of tacosobjectitem)) As Boolean

    Return True

End Function
```

This now turns the anyobjectname into a list of my object.  I cant understand why i couldnt use BodyStyle:- Wrapped but it works so im happy.  Hope it helps someone out there.